# Movie during "4:30 movies" that showed every Friday in NYC in the late 80s

Tags: story-identification, movie

During the late 80s in NYC there used to be the 4:30 Movie. I remembering watching Laserblast on it for the first time. There was a movie, that I don't remember much about except that someone was hiding in a room and a small ship or device was cutting a hole through the door with a laser in a circular pattern. The ship or device was basketball sized.

Anyone know the name of that short or movie?

Comment: Anything else you can remember about the film? Was it a horror film or action? Was it in space station/ship or on earth? What did the basketball device look like? The Phantasms series features a killer robot thing that looks like a chrome ball, but it has drills and claws sticking out of it.

Comment: It was a scifi thriller. It was on earth, a house. I remember person running into the room to hide, shutting the door behind themselves. HMM..I am pretty sure it was a some sort of what looks like a miniature space ship.

Answer (score 4):

"The Day Time Ended"(1980)?

It takes place in a house in the desert and there is a miniature spaceship shooting a laser through a door while the family hides in the room. Here is the scene from YouTube.